# Refresh Activity Problem

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh

I have an application with a list of video files with play button. When the user clicks play button, a separate activity starts through intent where the video is played. What I want is that when I click the back button when the video file finishes, I want the mainActivity to be refreshed (the mainActivity is the activity that started the activity for playing video file).

Any useful suggestions please??

Answer (score 0):

Put your "refresh"-code in the Main-Activity's `onStart`-method.

See Androids [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the code that can be used for refreshing an activity. Shall I use onCreate method??

Comment: I guess you want to repopulate your `ListView`? This would be the place to put this code so it gets executed every time this Activity gets in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` and then handle the different results.